# How to get CMD output in HTA file within JavaScript

Tags: cmd, activex, jscript, wsh, hta

I run some CMD commands in my HTA file like

```
<script>
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WShell.run('cmd /c the_first_command');

WShell.run('cmd /c the_second_command');
</script>
```

and the first command may need a time to be fully executed, for example a few seconds

I need to run the next command only after the CMD output says that the previous task is fully completed.

As I understand, after the first command I can run an interval for example

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {

    var cmd_output_of_the_first_command = ???;

    if(~cmd_output_of_the_first_command.indexOf('A text about the task is completed')) {
        clearInterval(timer);

        WShell.run('cmd /c the_second_command');
    }

}, 500);
```

So the question is how to get the CMD output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer:

```
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var WShellExec = WShell.Exec('cmd /c the_first_command');

var WShellResult = WShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll();
if(~WShellResult.indexOf('A text about the task is completed')) {
    WShell.Run('cmd /c the_second_command');
}
```

No need in any interval

OR

just
execute CMD synchronously one by one without the need to check CMD output

```
WShell.Run('cmd /c the_first_command', 0, true);
WShell.Run('cmd /c the_second_command', 0, true);
```